# is it possible to write CSS for all Angular "hosts" or do we have to select each host individually

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors

The [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host) for `:host` does *not* mention that we can style *all* host elements at once. I have added this CSS at a “global” level:

```
:host {
    width: 100%;
}
```

but there was no effect. However, this works fine in the CSS at the component level:

```
:host(app-search) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

where `app-search` is a component, `app-search.component.ts`.

Is is possible to write a `:host` selector for all components or must this be declared multiple times at the component level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By its very definition (or specification), `:host` **can never be used at a global level**. It is created to use from component level and to **select the parent** component (which is called `shadow host`) **from the children** (which is called `shadow tree`).

For more clarification, Angular's `:host` selector is a special selectors from the world of *shadow DOM style scoping* (described in the [CSS Scoping Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#host-selector) page on the [W3C site](https://www.w3.org/)).

The angular documentation clearly specifies that you should use this selector to select the parent component from within the child component. But it may seem unclear to you if you don't have any idea how shadow tree works. [see the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host).

If you need to style any component from a global stylesheet, there is a `style.css` file automatically added at a global scope in Angular. Just put your CSS in that file and you can find it available globally in all components.

Component level CSS files make your CSS modular. This is a great feature because:

- You can use the CSS class names and selectors that make the most
  sense in the context of each component.
- Class names and selectors are local to the component and don't collide with classes and selectors
  used elsewhere in the application.
- Changes to styles elsewhere in the
  application don't affect the component's styles.
- You can co-locate
  the CSS code of each component with the TypeScript and HTML code of
  the component, which leads to a neat and tidy project structure.
- You
  can change or remove component CSS code without searching through the
  whole application to find where else the code is used.

Although it is configurable, I strongly recommend not to use `ViewEncapsulation.None`. It will make kill all your CSS modularity which you can avail easily using global CSS files without affecting the scoping restriction.

Comment: correct: “[I] don't have any idea how shadow tree works” …will look at the docs referenced above :)

Comment: i also see that i can write `:host { width: 100%; }` to an external file and then use `@import` on the component level

Comment: @rasx `@import` just pull the content of the external file to the working file. It behaves like you copy the code from the external file and paste it into the working file. Thus, it should work. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your app-search.component.ts file, you could set:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

like this

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app-search.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app-search.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

This prevents you from having to rewrite styles and enables styles on a global level.

You could also try applying the styles directly into the index.html file. These styles will also be global, preventing you from rewriting styles at the component level.

Comment: You can also use the `style.css` files generated with Angular which is already effective globally.

Comment: I recommend not to use the `ViewEncapsulation.None` which means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and protections don't apply. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.